# I want to combine jQuery, AJAX, and Flask, but I can't get the response from the server to write on the template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flask

I'm designing a form to create families in a Flask based database app. Basically, a user can search for a clients in the database, and each row of the search results will have a "Add" button. When the user clicks the button, the client will appear in a list at the top of the form. Once all the clients are added, the user can then click another button that will create the family and commit the changes to the database.

I successfully linked the "add" button to an AJAX request, and I can see it on the console output (with the correct information) whenever I click it, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to return all the necessary data from the server and write it to the template.

I've included the relevant code below. I have a feeling the error lies somewhere in my routing function, but since I'm new to AJAX, jQuery, and JavaScript, it's hard for me to tell exactly what's going wrong. Please send help!

### routes.py

```
@app.route('/create_family', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def create_family():
    prefill = {'created_by':current_user.id}
    form = CreateFamily(data = prefill)
    # This if block handles the client search
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        clients = Client.query
        if form.first_name.data:
            clients = clients.filter(Client.first_name.like('%{}%'.format(form.first_name.data)))
        if form.last_name.data:
            clients = clients.filter(Client.last_name.like('%{}%'.format(form.last_name.data)))
        return render_template('create_family.html', form = form, clients = clients.all())
    # Logic for the AJAX 'GET' request
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        if request.args.get('clientID'):
            clientid = request.args.get('clientID')

            # Queries DB for client information
            client = Client.query.filter(Client.id == clientid).first()

            # HTML to insert to the family table in the form
            row = '<tr><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td></tr>'.format(client.id,client.first_name,client.last_name,client.gen.gender,client.dob.strftime('%m-%d-%Y'))

            # I'm not sure if this is right, or how I should change it
            return jsonify(result=row)
    else:
        return render_template('create_family.html', form = form)
return render_template('create_family.html', form = form)
```

### create_family.html

```
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'styles/main.css') }}">
      <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='javascriptfile.js')}}"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>

<!-- I omitted some of the template for brevity -->

<!-- This is the table I want to add to-->
<table class="familyView">
        <tr class="familyHeader">
            <th>Client ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Date of Birth</th>
        </tr>
    </table>


<!-- I omitted some of the template for brevity -->

<!-- This is the table I want to add to-->
<form action="" method="post"><br>
{% if clients %}
    <table class="clientView">
    <tr>
        <th>Client ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Date of Birth</th>
    </tr>
    {% for c in clients %}
    <tr>
        <td class="clientID">{{ c.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ c.first_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ c.last_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ c.gen.gender }}</td>
        <td>{{ c.dob.strftime('%m-%d-%Y') }}</td>
        <td><button class="addBtn" type ="button">Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor%}
</table>
</form>
{% endif %}
```

### javascriptfile.js

```
window.onload=function(){

$(".addBtn").click(function() {
    var $recordToAdd = jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('.clientID').text();
    console.log("clientid: " + $recordToAdd);

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: 'create_family',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {'clientID': $recordToAdd,},
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    })
});

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple issues here. First and foremost, when I was refreshing the page I wasn't refreshing the javascript. By doing a hard-reset (Shift+F5) I was able to figure out some of the other problems.

Second, when I was trying to append a row from the table at the bottom of the page instead of the top I was trying to use an unnecessary ajax request. That step can be done with just jQuery

```js
$(document).on("click", ".addBtn", function() {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
        tr.find("input").attr("class", "rmBtn");
        tr.find("input").attr("value", "Remove from Family");
        $(".familyView").append(tr);
    });
```

Third, I had to rewrite the function in `routes.py` to change a few things about my approach. I changed it so that the search results were displayed using AJAX and jQuery, so the page didn't have to be refreshed every time a new search was made.

```py
@app.route('/create_family', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def create_family():
    prefill = {'created_by':current_user.id}
    form = CreateFamily(data = prefill)
    if (request.method == 'GET') and request.args.get('client_ids'):
        ids = request.args.get('client_ids').split(',')
        print('ids: {}'.format(ids), file = sys.stderr)
        program = request.args.get('program')
        if len(ids) != 0:
            new_family = Family(program_id = program, 
                                created_date = datetime.utcnow(), 
                                created_by = current_user.id)
            db.session.add(new_family)
            db.session.flush()
            fam_id = new_family.id
            for cid in ids:
                new_mem = FamilyMember(family_id = fam_id, client_id = cid)
                db.session.add(new_mem)
            data = {'message': 'Family {} created at {}'.format(fam_id, new_family.created_date), 'code':'SUCCESS'}
            db.session.commit()
            return make_response(jsonify(data), 201)
        elif len(ids) == 0:
            print('this is an error', file = sys.stderr)
            data = {'message': 'Cannot create a family with no members', 'code':'ERROR'}
            return make_response(jsonify(data), 401)
    return render_template('create_family.html', form = form, client = client)
```

I know this isn't the best explanation of what I fixed, but now that I'm a few days removed from the original question I can't remember exactly what was giving me the most trouble.